# Term for someone that makes themselves sad to pass it onto others?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, psychology, criminology, emotional-expression

Is there a term for somebody that will purposely make themselves feel sad, and perhaps other negative feelings, with the intention of making another person feel them too?

This would be a way of emotionally hurting someone, without having to physically touch them.

I am not looking for strictly academic literature, rather something high level to get an understanding of this, what it is called, and other information from a birds' eye view.